# How to use Strong_Parameters in Rails 4 with Mongoid, if it throws Unpermitted parameters: (model_name) error on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, geospatial, strong-parameters

I am trying to use embedded relationship in MongoDB by using Mongoid with Rails 4.1.6. I have embedded an array of location data in my user model, as I will be adding user's location after every 5 minutes of interval.

This issue is:
I can add data to my database using IRB or Mongo Shell. But when I use my applications front end, it doesnt pass the embedded attributes. Ultimately document contains only user name which is the field of user model.

I tried to put the user_params in consol then I saw the below error :

> Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-21 05:04:04 +0100
>   Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S5QKXuzEZID7eEjfhVWcYyLjEpi+Y3NVWt9cy/aEKOc=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Appuvaa4", "coord"=>{"lat"=>"40.23", "long"=>"33.33", "alt"=>"33.22"}}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
>   Unpermitted parameters: coord
>
> ---

Unpermitted parameters: coord
{"name"=>"Appuvaa4"}

---

I cant understand why it says Unpermitted parameters: coord, however I have used rails strong_parameters as below.

Please let me know whats wrong with my code.

I also read about the geospatial data storage in MongoDB which seems great. I would really appricaite if anyone could guide me any reference or links on How to store geospatial data with embedded document. So taht instead of storing data like this I will use geospatioal data storage as later I will also be implementing an algorithm over the stored data.

I suppose this issue is only related with Strong_parameters, so It wouldnt be problem if i change it to mongos Geospatial after this resolved.

`Private
   def user_params

```
   params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                               :coords_attributes => [:lat, 
                                                      :long,:alt])

#I also Tried this 

params.require(:user).permit(:name, {:coords => [:lat, :long, :alt])
end `
```

But, both approach didnt work for me. 
Below is rest of my code:

User Controller

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)
    puts '**********************************************'
    puts user_params

    puts '*****************************************'

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end




  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params

        params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                                   :coords_attributes => [:lat, 
                                                          :long, 
                                                          :alt])
    end

end
```

User.rb

```
    class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  field :name


  embeds_many :coords, class_name: "User"
  #embeds_many :locations

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :coords
   #accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations


end
```

Coord.rb

```
   class Coord
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :lat
  field :long 
  field :alt

  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :coords

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <h3>Co-ordinates</h3>
  <%= f.fields_for :coord do |c| %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= c.label :Latitude %><br>
    <%= c.text_field :lat %>
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= c.label :Longitude %><br>
    <%= c.text_field :long %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= c.label :Altitude %><br>
    <%= c.text_field :alt %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you try this: `params.require(:user).permit(:name,:coords)`

Comment: I have tried but it still gives the same result. unpermitted :coords

Comment: have you solved this? try passing :id as well: `params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                               :coords_attributes => [:id,:lat, 
                                                      :long,:alt])`

Comment: No @Ali It still doesnt work. Can you suggest How should i design my models if I want a document like below. Where I will be updating locations document every now and then by pusing user's current co-ordinates.  

{ _id : ObjectId(...),
  name : "...",
  locations : [ {
                 time : "timestamp" ,
                 loc : [ 55.5, 42.3 ]
                } ,
                {
                 time : "timestamp",
                 loc : [ -74 , 44.74 ]
                }
              ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your posting JSON.  This worked for me posting JSON on my issue.

You have:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, 
                                   :coords_attributes => [:lat, 
                                                          :long, 
                                                          :alt])
```

But needs to be:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, {:coords => [:lat, :long, :alt]})
```

Here's additional information on the issue.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L246-L247